# Is there a way to represent 0 as a void pointer in F#

Tags: f#, interop

In OpenGL, normally a call to `gl.TexImage2D` requires a `void*` as the final data parameter. It's possible to pass the data later and so the last parameter can also be set to `0`. In F#, I've not found a clean way to cast `0` to a `voidptr`.

The following works for me but is there a cleaner solution?

```
  let emptyData: array<byte> = [||]
  use emptyPtr = fixed emptyData
  let voidPtr = emptyPtr |> NativePtr.toVoidPtr
  gl.TexImage2D(
    GLEnum.Texture2D,
    0,
    int GLEnum.Red,
    atlasWidth,
    atlasHeight,
    0,
    GLEnum.Red,
    GLEnum.UnsignedByte,
    voidPtr
  )
```

Comment: Try 0n for the last parameter.

Comment: @JimFoye that's a `nativeint`. It's a `voidptr` I need. `0n` does not work in this case.

Comment: It works for me, I set up a sample project using OpenGL.Net. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I'm using Silk.NET OpenGL library so it probably doesn't have that overload.

Comment: Yeah, I see that.

Comment: Try IntPtr.Zero.ToPointer().

Comment: Try ``Unchecked.defaultof<_>``.

Comment: @JimFoye I could have sworn I tried `IntPtr.Zero.ToPointer()` but that one did the trick. Thanks so much! If you create an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @dumetrulo thanks for your suggestion. It does work but seems a little cryptic compared to `IntPtr.Zero.ToPointer()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `voidptr` is an alias for `System.Void*`, but the .NET compilers don't like us to use this type directly. So `IntPtr.ToPointer()` is provided to convert any pointer to a void pointer. In your case, you want to convert a null pointer (i.e., `0n`), so you can use

```
IntPtr.Zero.ToPointer()
```

You could also use `0n.ToPointer()`, and as the other commenter pointed out, `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` also works, as the compiler can infer what you need here. (`IntPtr.Zero.ToPointer()` is the most readable, IMO).

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks very much, Jim.

Comment: @PhilT You're welcome. Honestly, every time I have to deal with pointers in .NET, I have to reread the docs. The funny thing is, I used to do C++ and was entirely comfortable with pointers. They are actually harder to work with in .NET (IMHO).